# Set default selected item of ListView Alert Dialog in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have created a dialog with a custom `ListView` that models a `Spinner` display, and originally it starts out with the value "Select Gender".

When the dialog opens it prompts for a selection (just like a spinner). If the selection gets selected again, it shows the same options, but doesn't indicate which option has already been selected.

**Example:**
Default Value: "Select Gender"
Dialog opens with no selection
User selects: "Male"
User reopens dialog...
Dialog opens with no selection

(**I'd like it to have "Male" selected, since that was their last selection**)

Here's my code so far:

```
genderItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gender_array);
genderAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, genderItems);

genderDrop.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Builder genderBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.gender_prompt)
                    .setAdapter(genderAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        inputGender.setText(genderItems[which]);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog genderAlert = genderBuilder.create();
                genderAlert.show();
                genderAlert.getListView().setSelection(0);
            }
            return false;
        }
});
```

`genderAlert.getListView().setSelection(0)` **doesn't set the default selected** as "Male"
`genderAlert.getListView().setSelection(1)` **doesn't set the default selected** as "Female"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Figured it out:

I switched from `.setAdapter` to `.setSingleChoiceItems` which has an argument for the default selection. Then all I had to do was create a global variable that got set each time I clicked an option. The global variable is initially set to -1 so no option is selected, then once I click on something it gets set to the position and the next time the dialog is created the selection reflects my previous selection. See below:

```
Integer selection = -1;

genderItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gender_array);
genderAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, genderItems);

genderDrop.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Builder genderBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.gender_prompt)
                    .setSingleChoiceItems(genderAdapter, selection, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            inputGender.setText(genderItems[which]);
                            selection = which;
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                AlertDialog genderAlert = genderBuilder.create();
                genderAlert.show();
            }
            return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: What is `genderDrop` here?

Comment: Oof this was super long ago so I'm not even sure I remember. I think it was likely a button of some sort. `genderDrop` is a bit of a misnomer in that sense, since it actually just opened up an `AlertDialog`.