# Set single choice AlertDialog default item in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using the following code to create an AlertDialog

```
    CharSequence[] array = {"Font1", "Font2", "Font3", "Font4"};
    callback = (DialogClickListener) fragment;

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 
    builder.setTitle("Font Settings")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(array, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    selected = array[arg1].toString();
                }
            })
           .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
              }
          })
          .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                callback.onYesClick(selected);
            }
        });
```

How can I set an element to be selected by default? Please help :)

Comment: Same question is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188980/set-selected-item-of-listview-alert-dialog

Comment: you are already doing that. mean your first item is selected in your code. if you want to select second item then just change 2nd perameter of setSingleChoiceItems. like setSingleChoiceItems(array,1,,); then your 2nd item is selected by default.

Comment: check my ans : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15764372/1381827

Comment: How unobservant I am, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @JDroid: sorry I can't, I don't have the required reputation...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

just change 2nd perameter of `setSingleChoiceItems` method like below.. change it to 0,1,2,3

```
.setSingleChoiceItems(array, 2,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                selected = array[arg1].toString();
                            }
                        })
```

as per above code your 2nd item is selected by default.

Comment: who give downvote here?? this is correct ans.. it is working well..

Comment: Just goes to show that it really does pay to RTFM.

Comment: Would you be able to help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327170/remember-what-was-selected-in-single-choice-alertdialog

Comment: how to set custom typeface to array of setSingleChoiceItems?

Answer (score 10):

When you call

```
builder.setTitle("Font Settings")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(array, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){...
```

The second parameter should specify the item checked by default, as the [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setSingleChoiceItems%28java.lang.CharSequence%5B%5D,%20int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) specifies