# Remember what was selected in single choice AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog` which displays an array into a single selected choice:

```
    protected boolean blFrom, blTo;
protected void showSelectToDialog() {
    boolean[] checkedDate = new boolean[toDate.length];
    int count = toDate.length;

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener setD2 = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            onChangeSelectedTo(which);
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select To Year");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(toDate, count, setD2);

    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog2 = builder.create();
    dialog2.show();
}

protected void onChangeSelectedTo(int j) {
    bTo.setText(toDate[j]);
    sTo = ((AlertDialog)dialog2).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
    blTo = true;
    displayToast(String.valueOf(sTo));
    to = j;
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

What I want to do is the first time it loads it should display the default. Once I select a choice and the dialog closes and I bring up the same dialog again it should show the previously selected choice I made and scroll to it.

How do I accomplish it?

As of right now, I can get the selected position but what next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the chosen value in a variable of your `Activity` or using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: It's a "one" activity app so I only want it to remember until I exit the app.

Comment: Well, then the first option would be the way to go.

Comment: How would I retrieve it?

Comment: I guess you can pass the selected choice to the dialog in `setSingleChoiceItems` method.