# Create Simple list Dialog With Default Checked item

Tags: android, listview, simpledialog

I'm trying to showing a simple list dialog, with the default selected item by gray background. I know we can use `setItems()` to show the list, but how do I set the checked item background to gray?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);

builder.setTitle(elementInfo.getName())
       .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    editText.setText(items[which]);
                                    elementInfo.setValue(elementInfo.getElementListValues().get(which).getValue());
                                    updateSelection(elementInfo, which);
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            builder.create().show();
```

Following is the effort I want as Material Design Tutorial describes:
https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-simple-dialogs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default selected item of ListView Alert Dialog in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188980/set-default-selected-item-of-listview-alert-dialog-in-android)

Comment: yes, i need the same effect. However don't what the check radio of items for using SingleChoiceItems. I just what the simple string list with gray background selected item .(like the google MD guide says)